# sqlite - Insert based on field comparison on other table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table student_pop that has the following data:

```
 ID  GPA  LETTER
 1    84        
 2    92       
 3    55
```

I have another table grade_info that has the following data:

```
lettergrade MinimumGrade MaximumGrade
   A             93         100
   A-            90         92
   B+            87         89
   B             83         86
   B-            80         82
   C+            77         79
   C             73         76
   C-            70         72
   D+            67         69
   D             63         66
   D-            60         62
   E              0         60
```

I am looking to insert a letter grade based on the GPA and the data from the grade_info table.

I think it would go something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO student_pop (letter)
SELECT lettergrade
from grade_info
WHERE(select GPA from student_pop WHERE GPA >=(select MinimumGrade from grade_info) and GPA <=(select MaximumGrade from grade_info)
```

I have the logic of what needs to happen, but I can't seem to workout the correct INSERT syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `UPDATE` the table:

```
update student_pop
set letter = (
  select lettergrade
  from grade_info
  where student_pop.gpa between minimumgrade and maximumgrade
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8JsbgAkdjkH8U5XJqH83PR/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | GPA | LETTER |
| --- | --- | ------ |
| 1   | 84  | B      |
| 2   | 92  | A-     |
| 3   | 55  | E      |
```